# Add Hide/Show functionality to HTML style (NOT IN THE CSS DOCUMENT)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a node class defined as follows in the style portion of my HTML:

```
<style>
.node {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}
</style>
```

My question is can I possibly add hide text functionality on mouse-over in this style section/ what would this implementation look like. I know I could add it in the CSS or whatever, but this node class is written for some already existing js and html code from a third-party graph visualization library, so I'd like to modify the rest of the code as little as possible since I'm not too great at web-dev. Like maybe add a func to the node somehow? (Like I said I'm terrible at webdev)

This is due in like 6 hours so any help would be great TY!

Comment: "circle" and "text" are HTML elements ? They are missing from http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/elements.html

Comment: @nicolallias I guess that are svg elements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try `css`:

```
.node:hover {
    display: none;
}
```

But it will give you some glitch effects:

https://jsfiddle.net/zpe8t6r6/

Comment: You could use `opacity: 0;` instead

Answer (score 0):

You can write:

```
$(function(){
  $('css selector').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).visiblity('hidden');
  });
});
```

Comment: you should avoid javascript (especially jquery) when a single line of css do the trick

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to avoid the "glitch" problem with hover and all the css based solutions :

you have to play with svg rules and update the text color to transparent on hover.

DEMO :

```js
$(".node text").mouseenter(function(){
  $(this).attr("fill","transparent");
}).mouseleave(function(){
  // YOUR TEXT COLOR HERE
  $(this).attr("fill","#000");
  // if you want it to default :
  //$(this).attr("fill","");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
.node {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node text {
  font: 30px sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}
</style>

<div class="node">
  <svg width="300" height="150">
    <text x="35" y="40">mouse hover it</text>
    <circle cx="150" cy="100" r="20"></circle>
  </svg>
</div>
```